# Connection refused for 127.0.0.1 on OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, networking

I'm on a really strange situation.
I'm using MAMP and I can't access to my working directory from the `127.0.0.1`.
When I'm using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` it works because the `localhost` is redirected to the `::1` ipv6 address.
So, I can access to my local server only via ipv6.
I've tried to start a little server with Python and it doesn't work ( it works fine on my personal laptop using OSX El Captain ).

When I try with an other port than `80` it works but I need to use this port ..
It's not a conflict, when I'm running the Python server he is the only one to listen the port `80`

Do you have an idea about this trouble ?
Why I can use the ipv6 local address only ?